# Build gradle version code

Tags: android-activity, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android

I need to do some thing like this: I have application with `versionCode 10` after update I need to clear all cache in application's private storage directory. I want to do something in main's activity `onCreate` method like this:

```
if (versionCode == 11)
    FileUtil.getInstance().clearSystemCache();
```

How can I get `versionCode` in my `Activity` or how can I solve this problem in a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE`.

The Android Gradle plugin will automatically inject the `VERSION_CODE` constant into a `BuildConfig` class for you, along with a few other useful build configuration variables such as the version name and whether it is  a debug build.

Comment: ... and remeber, at this time (2014-09-24) Eclipse ADT plugin is not genereting this field ... it works only with gradle.

Comment: @AskQuestion, he is saying is that projects built in Eclipse using the ADT plugin will not generate the `VERSION_CODE` field. Any project using the Android Gradle plugin will work just fine (once you have build at least once to generate the `BuildConfig` class).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in your Activity

```
PackageInfo pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
String versionName = pInfo.versionName;
String versionCode = pInfo.versionCode;
```